# AsyncFileUpload Asynchronies Process?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, asyncfileupload

Working with the asp.net **AsyncFileUpload** control. Is it an asynchronies process? I noticed when selecting a file, a postback is performed. Viewing in Fiddler, all script and external CSS pages again are loaded. I have the control wrapped in an update panel.

I would not like the script and CSS pages to be loaded every time a file is uploaded. The code and Fiddler screen shot are posted.

[image]

I would not like the script and CSS pages to be loaded every time a file is uploaded. The code and Fiddler screen shot are posted.

[image]
**No code has been put in the Code Behind page.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal behavior, MS Ajax (Update Panels) does a full PostBack to the server (Highly inefficient) and updates only the section that changed. You can either cache JS and CSS files so that at least you get 304 responses or use some other method to do this.

Perhaps putting the AsyncUpload control in an iframe will work better for you?